# Is it possible to side load script-lab?

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

When I attempt to use Script-Lab from the Office Add-Ins Store, I'm getting this error:

> Sorry, Office 365 has been configured to prevent individual
>   acquisition of Office Store Add-ins.

My O365 Admin says I need to side load Add-Ins...

I downloaded the `script-lab-react-prod.xml` manifest to a shared folder on my network and followed the directions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

When I go to open the add-in in Word, it's not showing up.

Is it possible to side load the Script Lab Add-In? If so, any idea what I've missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure this out and the kind folks at Script Lab helped out.

You can find the solution here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/issues/743#issue-461091474

Comment: Link only answers are no good :( please provide details of your resolution in answer